# Maven: how to build jar and include as a dependency

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3

I have a multi module project. I am using eclipse and Maven 3. I wish to first build a jar (a standalone project with its own pom). This is not the problem.

The problem is this jar is included as a dependency of my multi-module EAR project (used by two of the wars). The code of the JAR will often change and will require building before the EAR project is built.

**How can I make this jar build prior to the EAR build in one action?**

Here's my setup:

```
parentProject (packaging=pom, dependency[filters down to wars]=jarProject)
earproject (packaging ear, parent=parentProject)
war1Project (packaging war, parent=parentProject)
war2Project (packaging war, parent=parentProject)
jarProject (packaging=jar, no parent)
```

Comment: Your jarProject should have the same parent as the others and create a dependency to the jarProject from the war prjects to it.

Comment: The jar project is standalone. It could be used in other projects. I just need to make sure im using the very latest code when I build my EAR

Comment: That it is used by other project does not prevent to put it into the multi module under the parentProject. This makes sure the jarProject is built before the war projects  and the ear is being built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your *jar project* as topmost `<module>` in your *multi-module EAR project's* POM.

See also [Maven: The Complete Reference, Multi-module vs. Inheritance](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book//reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit).

Comment: This I have tried. However it did not have the latest code and errored when published and tested  as it was still using old jar code. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: @MarkW And the result is? Can you supply the relevant sections of each `pom.xml`and the output of the build?

Comment: ...I tried in the parent pom as this is where the <modules> are

Comment: The result is a sucessful build, with the reactor summary showing parentProject, jarProject, war1Project, war2Project, earProject in that order all as success.

Comment: The problem was the maven build broke my workspace, so publishing from my workspace resulted in the old code being published. I just need to remember to clean my workspace after running a maven build.